# Cast an object to a data type?

Tags: c++, typecast-operator

How can I cast an object to a data type, say int / string? Following is an example code:

I want to be able to use the following add with `integers` and with `var`
example `var = <expression> + <expression> ; //expression can be int or var`

Here is the code of var:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class vars
{
public:
    vars(std::string Name):name(Name){value = 0;}
    void setValue(int val);
    int getValue(void) const; 
//  std::string getName(void) const;
    ~vars(void);
private:
    std::string name;
    int value;
};
```

and here is the code of add:

```
#pragma once
#include "action.h"
#include "vars.h"

class add: public action
{
public:
    add(vars& v, int s1, int s2):target(v),source1(s1),source2(s2){} //downcast the vars to int if needed, how to do so explicitly?
    virtual void excute ();
    ~add(void);
private:
    vars& target; //not sure of it
    int source1, source2;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have got a contructor that takes exactly one parameter (in this case `int`) the type of the parameter can be converted implicitly to a temporary object of type `vars`. You then simply have to overload the `operator+` for `vars`.

```
vars(int a); // Add this constructor
vars & operator+=(const vars other) {
    value += other.value; // Or some other operations
    return *this;
} // This as memberfuncion inside the vars class

vars operator+(vars left, const vars & right) {
    return left += right;
} // This outside the class
```

This is the straight forward solution.

It is better to define constructors with only one parameter as `explicit` to avoid unwanted implicit conversions. But if this is what you want you can go without it as well.

The other case in which you want to get an `int` (or some other type) as the result is solved by overloading the `operator`*type*. For example:

```
explicit operator int() { return value; } // Inside class definition

// Which is called like:
vars var("meow");
auto sum = 1 + int(var); // The C-Style
auto sum = 1 + static_cast<int>(var); // The better C++ style
```

Again the `explicit` is optional but saver.

Comment: in `auto sum = 1 + static_cast<int>(var);` will I get `1+var.value;` ? in other words, what is the value of var that I will get after cast it to an `int`

Comment: That depends on how you define `operator int()`. It is up to you *how* the cast works. But in this code example - yes.